# exit point of an arbitrary ray within a cube

Tags: collision-detection, game-engine

I am trying to determine the exit point of a ray once it has been determined that it's origin point is contained within a defined bounding box. My givens are:

-A bounding box defined by a min and max corner (center is calculable) 
-An arbitrary point within the bounding box 
-A direction vector associated with the arbitrary point

The goal would be to find the exit point (x, y, z) from the bounding box of a ray originating from the given point and extending along the direction vector as efficiently as possible. My Linear Algebra skills are lacking at best so any information is much appreciated.

For context, this would be for determining the point of exit from a cubic portal when a projectile/entity enters another cubic portal (arbitrary point is the center-point of the entity on the frame in which it overlaps the entrance portal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't remember enough linear algebra to solve it that way, but I think the problem can be solved like thus. Also I've given the answer in pseudo unity C# since that's what I'm most familiar with.

```cs
//-----Givens-----:

//Calculate the box's size in all dimensions and center given extents
Vector3 size,origin;

//The ray's start in world coordinates
Vector3 rawPoint;

//The ray's direction (magnitude doesn't really matter here)
Vector3 rawVector;

//-----Process-----:    

//Normalize direction
Vector3 vector=rawVector.normalize();

//Redefine the ray start reference frame to be from the center of the box
Vector3 point=rawPoint-origin;

//X-intercept
//Solving intercept of y=.5*size.y 
//and equation of line in x,y plane: y-point.y=(vector.y/vector.x)(x-point.x) gives:
float xIntercept=((.5*size.y-point.y)*(vector.x/vector.y))+point.x;

//But we need to make sure we don't exceed the box's size (the intercept can be outside the box)
if (xIntercept>.5*size.x){
    xIntercept=.5*size.x;
}
if(xIntercept<-.5*size.x){
    xIntercept=-.5*size.x;
}

//Then just do the same thing twice more for the other dimensions.
//...

//This is the intercept point as defined from the center of the box
Vector3 localIntercept=new Vector3(xIntercept,yIntercept,zIntercept);

//So we just need to shift it back again to world coordiantes
Vector3 intercept=localIntercept+origin
```

I believe you might also need to check that the point is actually in the cube to begin with. But that's fairly simple.

I'll leave the presumably much simpler looking linear algebra solution to someone else.

Comment: thanks for this, however my understanding following along with your math is that I will end up with a sizable error due to calculating from the centerpoint of the square. with projectiles being shot through my portal shifting everything around the center would get quite confusing so it's preferable to avoid this as much as possible.

Comment: oops. You're right; I left out a step. But you just need to shift it back to have it in world coordinates.